# PHP/JavaScript Not affecting selectbox

Tags: javascript, php

I created `JavaScript` bellow the `$titleBlock`, and when I load the page, it's not affecting the select-box. What should I change?

```
$titleBlock->addCell(
    '<select id="my-select" size="1" class="text" name="user_id">
    "'.$option_str.'"
    </select>'
);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var mySelect = document.getElementById('my-select');;
    var setBgColor = function (select) {
        select.style.color = select.options[select.selectedIndex].style.color;
    };
    mySelect.onchange = function () {
        setBgColor(this);
        document.form_buttons.submit();
    };
    if(-1 != mySelect.selectedIndex) {
        setBgColor(mySelect);
    };
</script>
```

Comment: this seems from yesterday's question

Comment: I haven't found any similar...

Comment: How are you outputting `$titleBlock`? Are you using some sort of framework? Is the HTML output what your expect?

Comment: It's similar to HTML table :)

Comment: Please edit your question and indicate that.

Comment: anyways what you need to do is use ajax to submit form so you selectbox wont be reloaded

Comment: @vinayakj , mate it won't even load `document.form_buttons.submit();` . It's realy not that problem. :)

Comment: ok..np.. what do you see in log? when `if(-1 != mySelect.selectedIndex) { console.log(mySelect.selectedIndex)
        setBgColor(mySelect);
    }`

Comment: It shows mySelect is null

Comment: that means you are not at all getting handle of select box try to put the script in onload and then try once

Comment: It worked, thanx! And thnx for that debuger, now I can check by myself these problems with JavaScripts! Post an answer I will mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what do you see in log? when

```
if(-1 != mySelect.selectedIndex) { 
   console.log(mySelect.selectedIndex);
   setBgColor(mySelect); 
}
```

If nothing then that means you are not at all getting handle of select box try to put the script in onload and then try that should work